# Excel VBA: Populating One Dimensional Array with Date Values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am attempting to loop through a list of supposedly consecutive timestamps and discover if there is a minute that is missing. If there *is* a minute missing, I'm hoping to store the previous minute in a one dimensional array.

How can I make an array of dates, and add values to it? I know a string array can be added to using "Split"--but how to do that with dates? Here is the basic code I am using.

```
Dim currentminute as Date, oldminute as Date
i=1
Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn).Value=""
 currentminute=Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn).Value
 If oldminute<>""
  If currentminute-.007>oldminute then
     array1()=array1 & oldminute then
     'How to add to array?
   End If
  End If
 Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn)<>currentminute
  'Do calculations
   oldminute=currentminute
   i=i+1
  Loop
Loop
```

UPDATE: I had assumed that arrays were basically larger variables that you could add to. Mistaken! Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Your Do Until is missing a paranthises. I think it should read: `Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn).Value=""`

Comment: Have you googled "How to add an array in VBA"? I'm pretty sure you'll have more examples than we can provide.

Comment: Is this the actual code that is failing? That currently isn't even compilable.

Comment: `VBA.Strings.Split` does not "add to an array" - it *returns* a brand new array. In fact you *can't* add anything to an array.. not without copying it to a resized, new array that is. If you don't know how many elements you're going to need from the start, it's probably best to use a `Collection` rather than an array - especially if you're going to copy/resize that array multiple times over.

Comment: `redim preserve`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks--answered the question directly.